# How to override ApplicationVersion for Publish target in MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, clickonce

Is it a way to override the ApplicationVersion for the Publish target in a ClickOnce context?

I have created a custom build like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <ApplicationRevision>0</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>1.0.0.0</ApplicationVersion>
    ...
    <CustomBuildDependsOn>
        Build;
        CustomBeforePublish;
        PublishOnly;
    </CustomBuildDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="CustomBuild" DependsOnTargets="$(CustomBuildDependsOn)" />
<Target Name="CustomBeforePublish">
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(TargetPath)">
        <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="CurrentAssembly" />
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <PublishDir>$(OutDir)\publish\$(TargetName)\</PublishDir>
        <ApplicationVersion>%(CurrentAssembly.Version)</ApplicationVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Text="BeforePublish PublishDir = $(PublishDir)" />
    <Message Text="BeforePublish ApplicationVersion = $(ApplicationVersion)" />
</Target>
```

The property PublishDir is correctly overrided and used by PublishOnly target while the property ApplicationVersion is not correct : the application manifest is always with the version 1.0.0.0.
And the log display :

> BeforePublish ApplicationVersion = 3.5.0.51263

What is the correct way to pass ApplicationVersion to the target PublishOnly or Publish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way i have found to do this, it's to relaunch the MSbuild with the property :

```
<PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <ApplicationRevision>0</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>1.0.0.0</ApplicationVersion>
    ...
    <CustomBuildDependsOn>
        Build;<!--First build to get the version-->
        CustomPublish;<!--Rebuild and publish with the correct version-->
    </CustomBuildDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="CustomBuild" DependsOnTargets="$(CustomBuildDependsOn)" />
<Target Name="CustomPublish">
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(TargetPath)">
        <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="CurrentAssembly" />
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <PublishDir>$(OutDir)\publish\$(TargetName)\</PublishDir>
        <ApplicationVersion>%(CurrentAssembly.Version)</ApplicationVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Text="CustomPublish PublishDir = $(PublishDir)" />
    <Message Text="CustomPublish ApplicationVersion = $(ApplicationVersion)" />
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Targets="Clean;Publish" Properties="PublishDir=$(PublishDir);ApplicationVersion=$(ApplicationVersion);">
</MSBuild>
```

I'm not sure it's a correct way but it work

Comment: From what I've read, the important thing is to set the property in a target that runs before the build target does.