Assign the Version of a C# project dynamically, according to the version of another referenced package
I want to set the Version property of a C# project, according to the Version attribute of a PackageReference.
That is, in my project I have a reference to a package "A" of version "1.2.3.4":
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="A" Version="1.2.3.4" />
</ItemGroup>

And I wish to have a reference to the Version attribute of the referenced package "A", and assign it to the value of the project version:
<PropertyGroup>
    <Version><!--use the version of "A"--></Version>
</PropertyGroup>

I tried several approaches, according to the syntax I saw here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-items?view=vs-2022 but none of these succeed.

Does your project really only have this one package reference? How would you go about selecting/filtering the package reference of A in order to get the version?

It's kind of weird to do this, but it got me interested. I tried it a little bit, but it doesn't seem to be possible. Maybe it could work with a custom build task, but I doubt it's worth the trouble when you could always do dotnet build /p:Version=0.1.2.3, i.e. an external process must read the package's version and pass it to the build step.

may be realted - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39290059/how-to-override-applicationversion-for-publish-target-in-msbuild -it's about overriding the version propertye during the build.

You should be able to achieve this using build customization, e.g. directory build properties. I recommend reading the sections regarding customization thoroughly to understand the concept, potential pitfalls, differences (e.g. between .props and .targets), etc.
Note: This approach will not work if you want to use e.g. NuGet package manager in Visual Studio, and have it automatically update your customization values. In the example to follow, the MicrosoftDependencyInjectionVersion value would not be updated if you were to go to NuGet PM view and update the package manually to 8.0.1 - the $(MicrosoftDependencyInjectionVersion) value would be overwritten with 8.0.1 directly in the csproj-file, not in your .props-file.
Example
Create a file at the root of your project named Directory.Build.props with the following content:
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
      <MicrosoftDependencyInjectionVersion>8.0.0</MicrosoftDependencyInjectionVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

You can reference the value 8.0.0 from your project files using $(MicrosoftDependencyInjectionVersion) (or whatever you name your properties).
Sample usage in a project file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Version>$(MicrosoftDependencyInjectionVersion)</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="$(MicrosoftDependencyInjectionVersion)" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

And a simple Program inside said project:
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] _)
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        Console.WriteLine(assembly.FullName);
        var diAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection));
        Console.WriteLine(diAssembly?.FullName ?? "di assembly is null");
    }
}

Should output:
ConsoleApp21, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60

And the file's version information should also tell you the same:

